# Как правильно реализовать маппинг generic классов, и возможна ли при этом передача параметров?

Tags: c#, automapper

Всем добрый вечер. У меня старый проект, в котором не было automapper'a. Сейчас я добавляю его.

Ранее, за маппинг отвечал следующий класс и метод:

```
internal static class PaginatedListExtensions 
{

    internal static PaginatedDto<TDto> ToPaginatedDto<TDto, TEntity>(
        this PaginatedList<TEntity> source,
        IEnumerable<TDto> items) where TDto : IDto 
    {

        return new PaginatedDto<TDto> 
        { 
            Items = items,
            PageIndex = source.PageIndex,
            PageSize = source.PageSize,
            //others
        };
    }
}
```

Собственно при маппинге можно было просто передать параметр `IEnumerable<TDto> items`. **Пример использования в старой версии:**

```
return affiliates.ToPaginatedDto(
           affiliates.Select(af => af.ToAffiliateDto()));
```

Однако теперь я пытаюсь использовать automapper.
Вот моя регистрация:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(PaginatedList<>), typeof(PaginatedDTO<>))
                       .ConvertUsing(typeof(PaginatedListDTOConverter<>));
```

Вот мой конвертер

```
public class PaginatedListDTOConverter<T> : 
    ITypeConverter<PaginatedList<T>, PaginatedDTO<T>> where T : IDTO
{
    public PaginatedDTO<T> Convert(ResolutionContext context) 
    {
        var paginatedList = (PaginatedList<T>)context.SourceValue;

        return new PaginatedDTO<T>
        {
            //Items = items 
            ////items - хочется передать параметром

            PageIndex = paginatedList.PageIndex,
            PageSize = paginatedList.PageSize,

            //Others
        };
    }
}
```

Стандартное использование, которое фактически не работает без передачи внешнего параметра `IEnumerable<TDto> items`:

```
var dest = Mapper.Map<PaginatedList<Article>, PaginatedDTO<Article>>(source);
```

**Первая часть** вопроса в том, нормальна ли такая реализация маппинга generic классов?

**А вторая часть** - самая главная, как возможно **передать при маппинге параметр `IEnumerable<TDto> items`, как в старой версии**, и использовать его в конвертере например, передав в поле `Items` класса `PaginatedDTO` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня в свое время была та же задача, в итоге решил использовать параметризированные обертки (самописные, по сути упрощенные ваши старые маппинги) над AutoMapper'ом. Потому что штатный способ выглядит неочень:

```
public class PaginatedListDTOConverter<T> : 
    ITypeConverter<PaginatedList<T>, PaginatedDTO<T>> where T : IDTO
{
    public PaginatedDTO<T> Convert(ResolutionContext context) 
    {
        return new PaginatedDTO<T>
        {
            Items = context.Options.Items["items"];
            // ...
        };
    }
}'


var dest = Mapper.Map<PaginatedList<Article>, PaginatedDTO<Article>>(
    source, opt => 
    opt.Items["items"] = affiliates.Select(af => af.ToAffiliateDto()));
```